# Use special symbol (<, >) in layout design in Android

Tags: android, xml, symbols, xml-layout

I need two navigation buttons with their texts are `<` and `>`. However, the compiler doesn't allow me use those symbols, even if I use `\<` and `\>`.

Is there anyway to put these symbol into the XML design file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `&lt;` for <
Use `&gt;` for >
Use `&amp;` for &.

etc.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me the complete list for all symbols please? Google doesn't work well with symbols.

Comment: Check these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: See [this page](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php).

Comment: hei nanne,how can i use this?suppose i need to desplay a text including <cuisine>Cuisine: Thai,Chinese &   Vietnamese</cuisine>.but here this "&"" can not use here rather i have to use "and".how can i use "&" inside a text line????

Comment: If you need an '&' you use `&amp;`, just like the answer says.

Answer (score 4):

Use `&#60;` for <

Use `&#62;` for >

Use `&#38;` for &

use `&#34;` for "

for complete [List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)   of symbol

use &#  decimal code of the symbol  ; as above

Enjoy Programming..

Answer (score 2):

It is encouraged for Android programmers to store String values in res/values/strings. If you add a String here, you can reference it in your xml file like so: `android:text="@string/mystring"`

Answer (score 1):

Declare this in `string.xml` and use:

```
<string name="sna">Synonyms &amp; Antonyms</string>
```

And simply call this in:

```
<TextView 
    android:text="@string/s_n_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

---

> Use `&lt;` for <
>
> Use `&gt;` for >