# "Multiple annotations found at this line"

Tags: android

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
    - The value of attribute "android:text" associated with an element type "Button" must not contain the '<'

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="<"
  android:id="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />
```

there is error is line:

```
  android:text="<"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use special symbol (<, >) in layout design in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125160/use-special-symbol-in-layout-design-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout files are just xml and the & symbol is not allowed by itself.
You will need to use "&followed by the predefined name" to use that symbol.

The below are the various xml and html attributes that can be used in programming
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML